# Umbraco 7 - Custom Routing VS IContentFinder or both?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm building a website that is a SPA and I want to use Umbraco as a back end.

The sites content is currently coming from static JSON files, I want Umbraco to replace these JSON files by genrating the JSON based on what is in the CMS.

As a first step I have put the website with its static files in to an Umbraco Installation. Created a home node with a template.

This is working correctly. I have also aranged all the content for the JSON file in to logical nodes in the Umbraco content tree.

Take these URLs for an example

```
/data/nl/news.json

/data/en/news.json
```

How can I map BOTH of these URLs to a specific content node in Umbraco?

In my case I have:

```
-Home (Template with SPA)
  -News (THIS IS THE NODE I WANT THE URLS TO MAP TO)
      -NewsItem
      -NewsItem
```

When the request hits that node I want to read the URL and then go and get the correct content from the children and return it as JSON.

Not 100% sure if I should be trying to set up some custom routes so the URL's hit a controller, or the IContentFinder, or possibly a combination of both.

Any ideas?

Comment: cant you just set a template on those nodes that returns the json and bind the two languages to the root?  so from your client you should be simply able to call /nl/news/ or /en/news to have the data you need

Comment: Are /data/nl/ and /data/en/ real Umbraco nodes, or are the nodes that you want these to point to elsewhere?